# convert string with hexa to byte

Tags: java

I've a String with value `0xE20x800x93`.
I try to convert them like this and it works

```
byte[] bs = new byte[]{
(byte) 0xE2,(byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x93
};
```

But what I want is without doing the explicit casting, I need to convert it into a byte array.

Or at least a way to convert into a byte object, and not a byte[] object.

Comment: You would need to parse the string then convert the values.

Comment: Every byte with bit 7 set will need explicit casting

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one (albeit long) line:

```
byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(new ByteBuffer().putInt(Integer.parseInt(str.replace("0x", ""), 16)).array(), 1, 4);
```

This assumes you have exactly 3 bytes to get. If it's a variable length, the following code is more generic, but slightly more verbose, because it uses the length of the input to determine the eventual result size:

```
byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(new ByteBuffer().putInt(Integer.parseInt(str.replace("0x", ""), 16)).array(), 4 - str.length() / 4, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

try `DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(str)` from `javax.xml.bind` package